# Saving a file name as a input variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

very new to python so sorry for the silly question

I've created a user input interface

```
fn=input() 
#Where the user will input version32 for instance so effectively
fn=Version32
```

I've then imported a template word document using docx, which has been heavily modified based upon user input. I then want the file name output to be saved as "fn" or in this case Version32

```
output.save(r"C:\Users\XXX\XXX\XXX\'fn'.docx")
```

Where fn is a variable? Is this even possible, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Kind Regards!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can do this using f-string:

```
output.save(rf"C:\Users\XXX\XXX\XXX\{fn}.docx")
```

Comment: Genius, embarrassing how long I spent on that any you fixed my code with one letter!

Comment: Glad I could help. You can mark this as the answer if it worked!